# Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tentando fazer essa query mas a variável $teste entra vazia na query
mas quanod eu printo ela, eu vejo q existe

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Use App\User;

class BinarioController extends Controller
{
public function listanaoposicionados()
{
    $checar_patrocinador_posicionado_sql = User::where('indicacao', auth()->user()->name)->get();
    //dd($checar_patrocinador_posicionado_sql);

    foreach($checar_patrocinador_posicionado_sql as $patrocinado){

        $teste = $patrocinado->name;

        echo $teste;

        $verifica_existe_rede_binairo = User::where('referido_1','=',$teste )->orWhere('referido_2','=', $teste)->toSql();
        dd($verifica_existe_rede_binairo);

       //if($verifica_existe_rede_binairo->isEmpty()){ 
       //}

    }
     //return view('mmn.derramamento')->with('patrocinados',$patrocinados);
}
```

}

Comment: `$checar_patrocinador_posicionado_sql` aqui chega alguma coisa?

Comment: Opa virgilio, chega sim, entando q eu printei a variavel $teste
mas qnd eu debugo ( dd($verifica_existe_rede_binairo)) $teste vem vazio

Comment: Beverly Hills
"select * from `users` where `referido_1` = ? or `referido_2` = ?"

Comment: `->toSql();` ta assim e se colocar `get()`? retorna algo

Comment: não =\ retornada nada, ai eu usei o toSql(); pra ver oq tava entrando, e vi q n entrava nada

Comment: Collection {#231 ▼
  #items: []
}

Comment: Matheus não deve ta satisfazendo a pesquisa o contéudo da variavel $teste!?

Comment: rsrsrs o engraçado, q eu printo ela, e ela aparece, é coisa do capiroto velho

Comment: cara seguinte `User::where('referido_1','=',$teste )` o valor de `referido_1` é igual o valor de $teste?

Comment: ahammmm sim!!!!

Comment: complicado sem ver mesmo! parece um problema local

Comment: qual é a versão do laravel e do php? 
tente declarar $teste = null; antes do foreach  e faça assim
User::where('referido_1, $teste) mais uma coisa toSql não vai mostra o valor de $teste mesmo não.

Comment: Sério? jurava q mostrava, qndo do toSql aparece "?" e qnd do tosql aparece o maldito